# This little function to rotate a coin isn't working

Tags: python, function, flip

I'm doing a little program. This program works as follows:

1- U put how many coins do u want to have

2- U put all of them 'heads'

3- From the second coin, you start to flip the coins that the index a multiple of 2, when u finish you go back to the start and start again, but this time you'll start from the third coin and flip all that the index is multiple of 3, and continue like that, restart from the fourth coin and flip the multiples of 4 and continue until the end...

Example: 4 coins-->
heads, heads,heads,heads

1° time:
heads,talls,heads,talls,

2° time:
heads,talls,talls,talls,

3° time:
heads, talls,talls,heads.

I think this code is almost reaching it, but this function I built doesn't do the job of flipping the coin and change the 'mode' on the 'moedas' list

Vocab: Heads-cara / Talls - coroa /Coin(s)- moeda(s) /To flip - Virar (portuguese)

I'll apreciate any help to change some error on the rest of the code too.

```
def Virar(moeda):
    if moeda == 'cara':
        moeda = 'coroa'
    if moeda == 'coroa':
        moeda = 'cara'

    return moeda

qtde_moedas = int(input('How much coins do u want?'))
moedas=[]
while (len(moedas))<qtde_moedas:
    moedas.append('cara')

for divisor in range(2,len(moedas)):
    for index_num in range(len(moedas)):
        if (index_num+1)%divisor==0:
            moedas[index_num] = Virar(moedas[index_num])
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you pass `'cara'` to your function `Virar`; first it changes `moeda` to `'coroa'`, because it was `'cara'`. And then, it checks whether `moeda` is `'coroa'`, which is `True` now, so it turns it back to `'cara'`! So `Viara` *never* flips the coin as you wish. Instead, try using `elif` or `else`:

```py
def Virar(moeda):
    if moeda == 'cara':
        moeda = 'coroa'
    else:
        moeda = 'cara'
    return moeda
```

A shorter version, if you are interested, would be the following:

```py
def virar(moeda):
    return 'coroa' if moeda == 'cara' else 'cara'

qtde_moedas = int(input("How many coins do you want? "))
moedas = ['cara'] * qtde_moedas

for divisor in range(2, qtde_moedas + 1):
    for i in range(divisor - 1, qtde_moedas, divisor):
        moedas[i] = virar(moedas[i])

print(moedas)
```